# java.lang.SecurityException: Method class android.media.IAudioService$Stub$Proxy.isCameraSoundForced[] not available

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I'm getting the following error when calling Camera.open(cameraIndex) (Camera 1 API)

MethodInvocationProxy : Exception while calling method public abstract boolean android.media.IAudioService.isCameraSoundForced() throws android.os.RemoteException
                                            java.lang.SecurityException: Method class android.media.IAudioService$Stub$Proxy.isCameraSoundForced[] not available to instant apps

> 06-18 10:23:43.361 26240-26359/? E/Isotope: UID: [10185]  PID: [26240]
>   MethodInvocationStub : Exception while calling method
>   isCameraSoundForced
>                                               java.lang.SecurityException: Method class
>   android.media.IAudioService$Stub$Proxy.isCameraSoundForced[] not
>   available to instant apps
>                                                   at com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.ipc.proxies.SandboxEnforcer.enforceUnsupportedPolicy(PG:63)
>                                                   at com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.ipc.proxies.SandboxEnforcer.enforceUnsupportedMethodPolicy(PG:17)
>                                                   at com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.ipc.ProxyMethodHandler.handleMethod(PG:50)
>                                                   at com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.ipc.base.MethodInvocationStub.onTransact(PG:56)
>                                                   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453) 06-18 10:23:43.361
>   26274-26274/? E/Isotope: UID: [99000]  PID: [26274]
>   MethodInvocationProxy : Exception while calling method public abstract
>   boolean android.media.IAudioService.isCameraSoundForced() throws
>   android.os.RemoteException
>                                               java.lang.SecurityException: Method class
>   android.media.IAudioService$Stub$Proxy.isCameraSoundForced[] not
>   available to instant apps
>                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
>                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
>                                                   at com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.ipc.base.MethodInvocationProxy.readReply(PG:39)
>                                                   at com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.ipc.base.MethodInvocationProxy.invoke(PG:130)
>                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
>                                                   at $Proxy5.isCameraSoundForced(Unknown Source)
>                                                   at android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(Camera.java:260)
>                                                   at com.chegg.feature.wizard.camera.CameraActivity.getBackFacingCamera(CameraActivity.java:357)
>                                                   at com.chegg.feature.wizard.camera.CameraActivity.startCamera(CameraActivity.java:101)
>                                                   at com.chegg.feature.wizard.camera.CameraActivity.startCameraSafely(CameraActivity.java:79)
>                                                   at com.chegg.feature.wizard.camera.CameraActivity.onResume(CameraActivity.java:74)
>                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1286)
>                                                   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6987)
>                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4144)
>                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4245)
>                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3360)
>                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
>                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
>                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
>                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

android.hardware.Camera was deprecated in API level 21, while Instant Apps support devices only from API level 23. You need to use android.hardware.camera2 instead.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html

> The android.hardware.camera2 package provides an interface to
>   individual camera devices connected to an Android device. It replaces
>   the deprecated Camera class.

This issue was addressed in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38485484
where Engineers provided the following information:

> "Instant apps don't support the old deprecated android.hardware.Camera. They only support the camera2 APIs"

Answer (score 0):

Instant apps have restricted functionality, obviously that method is not supported. You can use `InstantApps.isInstantApp()` method to determine whether it is installed or instant app and call `isCameraSoundForced` only for installed.

More info: https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/reference.html

Comment: OK. Still, how do I overcome this error when using Camera 1 API Camera.open(cameraIndex). Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Instant apps run natively on Android O and on previous versions, they use google play services to run. So camera 1 is not supported in instant apps prior to API 26 as they don't run natively. However, you can use Camera 1 api in an instant app on API 26 and till the time Camera 1 api lives I would imagine.

However, I'm using camera 2 api in the instant app and camera 1 api in the installed app.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the current implementation of Google Play Services support of instant apps.

It will be fixed in a future release, at which point the android.hardware.Camera API should function correctly.

Unfortunately I don't have any specifics on the timeframe of the fix being available.